# confused about js function syntax

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I was doing some ES6 syntax practice on freecodecamp.org, having some difficulties to understand the context.I know this is called [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) in JS,

```
(function () {
    statements
})();
```

So, this is OK but why not I get the `..args` inside the **first** `sum` also instead of the inner `sum` only?

```js
const sum = (function(...args) {
  console.log(...args); //this shows nothing
  return function sum(...args) {
    console.log(...args); // this shows 1,2,3
    return args.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  };
})();
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3)); // 6
```

What if I modify the above snippet with this, they are doing the same thing right? is there any logical difference happening under the hood?

```js
function sum(...args) {
  console.log(args);
  return args.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3)); // 6
```

> The main problem is why a function `sum` returning another function
>   `sum` inside it.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal 'use strict' directive in function with non-simple parameter list`

Comment: @CertainPerformance edited, it was just copy pasting :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first code, the IIFE is being called with no arguments, see:

```
})();
```

So, the resulting `args` array is empty, when spread into a parameter list, the resulting parameter list is empty; there is nothing to log. `console.log` with an empty parameter list does not do anything. It *would* log something if you invoked the IIFE with at least one argument, though:

```js
const sum = (function(...args) {
  // Now, it shows something!
  console.log(...args);
  return function sum(...args) {
    console.log(...args); // this shows 1,2,3
    return args.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  };
})(9999);
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3)); // 6
```

In the second code, there's only one function, not a function wrapped inside another function, and that one function *is* always called with parameters. If you called it with *no* parameters and spread them into the `console.log`, you would see the same effect:

```js
function sum(...args) {
  console.log(...args);
  return args.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}
sum(); // 6
```

Comment: Ohh shit...I knew it... , how I forget it?, only god knows !!!!, I can pass arguments to an `IIFE`. at the end of it, thank you for reminding me the old thing very well, thanks again.